# How to declare event handler for an element which will be loaded via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button which loads using AJAX `<input>` after click. There is an event handler for it in my JS connected to a page. I tried to declare event handler for `<input>`'s in the same JS, but they doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
<button>load</button>
```

JS

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'additional.html',
        context: document.body,
    }).done(function(html) {
        $('body').append(html);
    })
});
$('input').click(function () {
    alert('aasd');
});
```

I have made [test page](http://testapi.eu5.org/gmm/ajax.html), but everything works only after inserting JS to Chrome's Webconsole(due to unknown reasons connected script in `<head>` doesn't work)

Comment: the key word is delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use event delegation `.on` in your case. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for full reference about `.on`

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click','input',function () {
    alert('aasd');
});
```

Comment: What if I want to show alert immideately after input appears? Without changing smth inside "$.ajax().done()" Is there any event listener for element appearing?

Comment: There is no implicit events for detecting the visibility changes of an input element in JQUERY. I could help you more if you provide some more info. :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#cl').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'additional.html',
    context: document.body,
}).done(function(html) {
    $('body').append(html);
})
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#cl').click(function () {
alert('aasd');
});
});
</script>

<button id="cl">load</button>
```